# Where did all of Harry's money come from?

Tags: harry-potter

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where did Harry's parents get all of their money from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/where-did-harrys-parents-get-all-of-their-money-from)

Harry Potter is able to pay for his Hogwarts education and all of his other expenses thanks to a large amount of wizard gold in an account in his name at Gringotts. Where did this money come from? Is it ever explained? As far as I remember, he inherited the cash from his parents. But (I think) James was poor, and Lily was Muggle-born - so where would she have gotten a large amount of wizard money?

Comment: I don't think Hogwarts charged tuition (@slytherincess?), and James was actually quite wealthy.  See the question Jeremy linked.

Comment: This is a duplicate question: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/3223/3500 Kevin -- there is a fund for economically disadvantaged students at Hogwarts for books, robes, wands, etc. Tom Riddle had to take advantage of this fund. However, as far as I know, Hogwarts does not charge tuition. Seeing as one year at a boarding school can easily run $45K+, Hogwarts charging tuition would seem impractical. ($45K US is 4468 galleons, 12 sickles, and 6 knuts in Wizarding currency, fwiw! :D )

Comment: Thanks y'all! I was posting from my mobile so the "similar question titles" little thingy didn't pop up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't remember any of the books mentioning that. The only time I believe it says anything is when Hagrid shows harry the vault in book 1.   It's possible that I may have missed something, but I have read each book at least twice.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Harry Potter Wiki](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Main_Page), [James Potter](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/James_Potter_I) (Harry's Father) came from a very wealthy family.  He was the only child and both his parents died in 1975 and 1981, leaving him the only heir to their fortune.

This was also mentioned at some point in *The Sorcerer's Stone*, but I forgot where.