# How rich is Sirius Black?

Tags: harry-potter, money, sirius-black

So we already have answers on [how rich Harry Potter is](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/12260/how-much-money-did-harry-potter-have), but the answer (while good) doesn't touch on how rich he is from later books.

> After Sirius died, he left everything to Harry, including what is supposedly the Black family fortune (it didn't go to Narcissa!)

My question is, how much did Sirius leave for Harry in terms of money and other assets?

Comment: Sirius' money initially came from his uncle did it not? He was later removed from the Black family tree for this act!

Comment: Presumably his house and all its contents would have gone to Harry. However seeing as Sirius was considered by the Ministry of Magic to be a killer and how the MoM check the wills of dead people, again assuming Sirius left a will, then this might impact on what Harry received from Sirius

Comment: Terraced house in need of some modernisation in London is a pretty sizeable inheritance to start with.

Comment: To correct myself, according to http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sirius_Black, Sirius was cleared of all charges after the Battle of the Department of Mysteries

Comment: he must have got a pretty sirius inheritance.

Comment: @MattGutting *groan*

Comment: @Randal'Thor I have to do what I'm good at :-D

Comment: Seven. He is seven rich.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A "reasonable amount of gold" when compared to  Harry's (but presumably less) plus everything inside Grimmauld Place.

Sirius left Harry his own personal fortune and possessions,

> "But first of all I must tell you that  Sirius’s will was discovered a week ago and that **he left you everything he owned.** (...) This is, in  the main, fairly straightforward,” Dumbledore went on. “**You add a reasonable amount  of gold to your account at Gringotts, and you inherit all of  Sirius’s personal possessions**."
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince - Chapter 3*)</sub>

The reasonable amount of gold probably came from his inheritance from his uncle Alphard, being that Sirius was imprisoned since he was 21.

> Yeah, I  camped out at your dad’s during the school  holidays, and then when I was seventeen I got a place of my own, **my Uncle Alphard had left me a decent bit of gold** — he’s been wiped off here too, that’s probably why — anyway,  after that I looked after myself.  I was always  welcome  at Mr. and Mrs.  Potter’s  for Sunday  lunch,  though.”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix - Chapter 6*)</sub>

We do know that Sirius had purchased a motorbike and a firebolt broomstick, so the inheritance wasn't completely intact when he bequeathed it to Harry.

The only possession of note that Sirius had was Buckbeak.

> There is also the matter of the hippogriff, Buckbeak. Hagrid has been looking after  him since Sirius died, but Buckbeak is yours now,  so if you would prefer to make different  arrangements —
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince - Chapter 3*)</sub>

Sirius also left Harry the Black Family house and slave.

> "The slightly  problematic part of  the legacy (...) is  that  **Sirius  also  left  you number twelve, Grimmauld Place**. (...) Black  family tradition decreed that the house was  handed  down  the direct  line, to  the next male with the name  of  ‘Black.’  Sirius  was  the  very  last  of  the  line  as  his  younger brother, Regulus, predeceased  him  and both were childless. (...) if you have indeed inherited the house, you have also inherited —” He flicked his wand for a fifth time, (...) “Kreacher.”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince - Chapter 3*)</sub>

Note that the house and everything in it was worth quite *a lot*.

> “Sirius?” said Mundungus, who did not appear to have paid any
>   attention to this conversation, but had been minutely examining an
>   empty goblet. “This solid silver, mate?”
>   “Yes,” said Sirius, surveying it with distaste. “Finest fifteenth-century
>   goblin-wrought silver, embossed with the Black family crest.”
>   <sub>(*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix - Chapter 5*)</sub>

He did not leave Harry the Black Family fortune as he never inherited it, having been written out of their inheritance. The house was an exception. Judging by the value of the house, if he would have inherited their fortune as well, his wealth would have easily dwarfed harry's.

Comment: There was no canon for being left out of the Black family inheritance. It may have gone another route, but we know that the other blacks (Narcissa and Bellatrix) didn't receive it (as Bellatrix was living at Malfoy manor). It definitely didn't go to Tonks either.

Comment: @Anoplexian - It was an assumption I made based on: A)Sirius having to call upon a special tradition about the house to get that and B)Sirius's fortune still being less than Harry's despite the wealth of the Blacks.

Based on Bellatrix's vault at Gringotts, it very likely went to her.

Comment: That was the Lestrange vault. Rudolphus Lestrange is a pureblood, and from the books when he's hanging around Voldemort, a wealthy one.

Comment: @Anoplexian - That's definitely possible, though I don't recall any specific mentions to Rudolphus being that wealthy.

Comment: What about Black's family gold.. I think being one of the richest pure blood families, Sirius must have inherited tons of gold from them

Comment: @prakharlondhe - He was written out of the inheritance when he ran away.

Comment: Then why did he inherit the Black House? Surely the death of all potential inheritable males had an effect on material inheritence?

Comment: @prakharlondhe - The house had special enchantments on it. Their money did not.

Answer (score 0):

G.James was correct that Sirius received his uncle's inheritance. And according to the quote below Sirius was left quite wealthy.

> Sirius's uncleAlphard, Walburga's brother, sympathised with his young nephew and left him a large inheritance, most likely causing Walburga to blast Alphard's name off, as well. Sirius was left financially independent by his uncle’s generous bequest.

In reference to what Sirius left Harry, I can't find a monetary value, a part from one fan fiction story. What Harry did receive from Sirius was

- The Black family home and all of its contents
- Sirius motorbike
- Kreacher
- The remainder of Alphards money as well as the remainder of the Black family fortune
- Buckbeak

Comment: Where is that quote from? I'm pretty sure it's not in any canon.

Comment: http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Sirius_Black. I'm currently researching to find any quotes from JKR or any other canonical sources

Comment: As usual wiki takes a somewhat vague canon quote and turns it into an oddly specific historical account.