# Who were James Potter's family?

Tags: harry-potter, jk-rowling

In the whole series we never know who were Harry's grandparents. He sees them in that magical mirror in the first book but it does not ever occur to him to ask about them from anyone. He never wonders how they died or where they lived nor he ever asks about any relatives from his father's side.

Why JKR never mentioned the Potters? Has she had any interview about this?

Comment: Possibly related: [Where did the Potters get all of their money from?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/where-did-harrys-parents-get-all-of-their-money-from/6327#6327)