# How much do Aurors earn?

Tags: harry-potter, money

In Harry Potter, we only know 2 children of Aurors, namely Harry and Neville. We know that Harry borders on obscenely rich, is there any evidence that Neville is similar? Or is Harry's fortune, to some extent, a family fortune?

Basically, how much money do Aurors actually earn?

Comment: Harry's money is a family fortune that predates his parents.

Comment: Were James and Lily Aurors?

Comment: James didn't work, and I don't think Lily did either. They were in the Order of the Phoenix, but that's it.

Comment: Mr Weasley works for the Ministry and earns precisely half a pittance.

Comment: "[Where did Harry's parents get all of their money from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3223/where-did-harrys-parents-get-all-of-their-money-from)"

Comment: No Aurors seem to have [told the internet](https://www.glassdoor.co.uk/Salary/Auror-Salaries-E1701454.htm?countryRedirect=true) how much they earn.

Comment: @Aegon Thank you for the constructive criticism, I will definitely bear it in mind for future questions. My main question was 'how much do they earn.' That is why I marked this as a duplicate. I felt that the other question (which didn't come up in my initial search due to different keywords) answered that. There was no issue of peer pressure, I just felt that I needed to mark this as duplicate.

Comment: @FezWasTaken I thought that the prophesy had referred to the one who would defeat the Dark Lord being the child of two aurors. I was wrong.

_"The one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord approaches ... Born to those who have thrice defied him, born as the seventh month dies ... And the Dark Lord will mark him as his equal, but he will have power the Dark Lord knows not ... And either must die at the hand of the other for neither can live while the other survives ... The one with the power to vanquish the Dark Lord will be born as the seventh month dies..."_

Comment: @Aegon It seemed like it covered it to me. I absolutely don't mind, and I didn't take constructive criticism as a negative in any way. I am pretty new here and the only way I will really improve is if people point out where I was wrong. That is why I thanked you. :)

Comment: The other question does not appear to contain any discussion of how much Aurors earn.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no exact figures in the books/movies. However, taking in account that Aurors are:

- considered an elite
- these positions are coveted by many
- require top (outstanding) school grades

we may deduce that an Auror career is very much desired, respected, and well paid. You may consider a muggle analogy of a top-ranking Police officer or a state attorney.