# What is the average wizard income in Harry Potter Britain?

Tags: harry-potter, money

<sup>*Inspired by [this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/165504/how-much-do-aurors-earn).*</sup>

In the books, we only see prices for various items in Wizard money. But how much do the wizards earn? What is considered a 'rich wizard' or a 'poor wizard' in terms of income? I know that some rich families (eg. The Malfoys) are rich due to accumulated wealth, but I am interested in income figures only.

Comment: What kind of average? Mean, median, or mode?

Comment: The same question here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20322/is-it-possible-to-approximate-an-average-wizards-wage (without an answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought about this a few months ago, as everybody must earn a living, right?

[A popular fan-site](http://wizardsandwhatnot.com/2016/02/27/how-much-do-wizarding-professionals-earn/) produced an article which may be of use.

It doesn't appear that they earn a great deal in short, however there are a few exceptions. Based on the maths from the article, I should think the average would be between £27,000 and £35,000. With a lack of lower earning examples it is hard to form a more accurate conclusion from this.

Comment: How does it compare to an average Muggle income?

Comment: In fairness, if the article is anything to go by, and their maths seems fairly close. I would say very comparable.

Comment: can it be expressed in Wizard currency (i.e. Galleons)?